# Why dosen't my code continue when y is enter?

Tags: java

I'm new to programming (Java) and stack overflow. My code works except when I run it and press <kbd>y</kbd> it keeps repeating "do I want to continue" and is stuck in a loop to nowhere (everything else works). Could someone please tell me why this is happening and what should I do to fix it.

```
import java.util.Scanner;
import java.text.NumberFormat;
import java.text.NumberFormat;
import java.util.Scanner;

public class ch03_ex3_DownloadTime {

    public static void main(String[] args) {
        int dSpeed = 0;
        int fSize = 0;
        Scanner sc = new Scanner(System.in);

        { // get the input from the user
            System.out.println("Welcome to the Download Time Estimator");
            System.out.print("Enter file size (MB): ");
            fSize = sc.nextInt();
            System.out.print("Enter download speed (MB/sec): ");
            dSpeed = sc.nextInt();
        }
        int dTime = fSize / dSpeed;
        int hours;
        int remainder;
        remainder = dTime % 3600;
        hours = dTime / 3600;
        int minutes;
        int seconds = remainder % 60;
        minutes = remainder / 60;
        String message = "\n" +
            "This download will take approximately " + hours + " hours " + minutes + " minutes " + seconds + " seconds \n";
        System.out.println(message);

        boolean isContinuing = true;
        boolean inputIsInvalid = true;
        while (inputIsInvalid) {
            System.out.print("Continue? (y/n): ");

            String choice = sc.next();

            if ("y".equalsIgnoreCase(choice)) {
                inputIsInvalid = false;
            } else if ("n".equalsIgnoreCase(choice)) {
                inputIsInvalid = false;
                isContinuing = false;
            } else {
                System.err.print("Error: Only valid answers are Y/N. ");
            }
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: Try printing the value of `choice` in the loop

Comment: Try using `sc.nextLine`

Comment: When I run it, it just asks if I want to continue. I press `y` and hit enter, and it exits. If I rerun it and press `n` and enter, it also exits. If I press `asdf`, it continues until I enter one of `y` or `n`, in which case it exits again. How do I reproduce your issue of it repeating over and over? Can you copy-paste from the terminal to show what happens, and explain how it's different from what you expected?

Comment: run:
Welcome to the Download Time Estimator
Enter file size (MB): 5555
Enter download speed (MB/sec): 1

This download will take approximately 1 hours 32 minutes 35 seconds 

Continue? (y/n): y
Continue? (y/n): y
Continue? (y/n): y
Continue? (y/n): d
Continue? (y/n): Error: Only valid answers are Y/N. n
BUILD SUCCESSFUL (total time: 39 seconds)

Comment: I'm using netbeans if that matters?

Comment: MadProgrammer if you mean on the String choice = sc.next() tried it did not work. thanks

Comment: I just ran it and get the same results as that other guy. It exits on both 'y' or 'n' due to the fact that they are both setting the check to false. No looping however.

Comment: How are you running it? works fine for me with netbeans.

Answer (score 0):

```
import java.util.Scanner;
import java.text.NumberFormat;
import java.text.NumberFormat;
import java.util.Scanner;

public class ch03_ex3_DownloadTime {

public static void main(String[] args)
{
test t=new test();
t.chk();

}


}



class test{
    public void chk(){
    int dSpeed = 0;
        int fSize = 0;
        Scanner sc = new Scanner(System.in);



        {         // get the input from the user
            System.out.println ("Welcome to the Download Time Estimator");
            System.out.print("Enter file size (MB): ");
            fSize = sc.nextInt();
            System.out.print("Enter download speed (MB/sec): ");
            dSpeed = sc.nextInt();
     }
        int dTime = fSize / dSpeed;
        int hours;
        int remainder;
        remainder= dTime % 3600;
        hours = dTime / 3600;
        int minutes;
        int seconds= remainder % 60;
        minutes = remainder / 60;
        String message = "\n" +
                         "This download will take approximately " + hours +  " hours "
                       + minutes  + " minutes "
                       + seconds + " seconds \n";
        System.out.println(message);

    System.out.println("do you want to retry");
    System.out.println("press 1 if yes");
    System.out.println("press 2 if no");

    int a=sc.nextInt();

    if(a==1)
    {
    chk();
    }

    else
    {
    System.out.println("thanks");
    }


    }
    }
```

Comment: you just want to ask if the user want to retry or not 
and if he want to the program will rerun..?